# How to show certain array on react JS with mapping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to make some hotel web page using React.js and I'm currently on the process to make the facilities page. I want to show the facilities description based on the button that the user click. How can I do that using mapping ? I already write some code and it show all the item from my array, not the button that the user click. Can someone help me please ?

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/Facilities.css'
import {Row, Col, Container} from "react-bootstrap"

const FacilitiesInfo = [
    {
        Name: "De' Spa",
        Description: "Spa Description is here",
        OpeningHours: "Opening Hours: 10.00am - 8.00pm",
        UpperLeftImg:"kamar1.jpg",
        BottomLeftImg:"IMG_9299.jpg",
        UpperRightImg:"",
        BottomRightImg:"",
        Id:"1"
    },
    {
        Name: "De' Resto",
        Description: "De' Resto is a restaurant in our hotel that serves up gourment and familiar savory food for breakfast, lunch and dinner. Room service available for 24 hours with many selction guaranteed to satisfy you anytime in the privacy of your room.",
        OpeningHours: "Open for 24 hours",
        UpperLeftImg:"",
        BottomLeftImg:"",
        UpperRightImg:"",
        BottomRightImg:"",
        Id:"2"
    },
    {
        Name: "Meeting Room",
        Description: "Meeting Room Description is here",
        OpeningHours: "Reservation by Whatsapp: +62-8234-6528-886",
        UpperLeftImg:"",
        BottomLeftImg:"",
        UpperRightImg:"",
        BottomRightImg:"",
        Id:"3"
    },
]

const Facilities = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid={true} className="p-0">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="FacilitiesHeader semibold">
                        <h1>Facilities</h1>
                        <hr style={{border:'2px solid', color:'#caa461', width:'25.7%', margin: '10px 0px 100px 51px'}}></hr>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid={true} className="text-center p-0">
                <Row className="FacilitiesList">
                    <Col md={12} lg={4}>
                        <button>
                            De' Spa
                        </button>
                    </Col>

                    <Col md={12} lg={4}>
                        <button>
                            De' Resto
                        </button>
                    </Col>

                    <Col md={12} lg={4}>
                        <button>
                            Meeting Room
                        </button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid={true} className="text-center p-0">
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12} lg={12}>
                        {FacilitiesInfo.map((show) =>{
                            const {Name, Description, OpeningHours, Id} = show
                            return(
                                <div key={Id} className="FacilitiesDesc">
                                    <h1>{Name}</h1>
                                    <h5>{Description}</h5>
                                    <h4>{OpeningHours}</h4>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid={true} className="p-0">
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12} lg={12}>
                        {FacilitiesInfo.map((show) =>{
                            const {UpperLeftImg, UpperRightImg, Id} = show
                            return(
                                <div key={Id} className="FacilitiesImg">
                                    <img src={UpperLeftImg} alt="Image 1"></img>
                                    <img src={UpperRightImg} alt="Image 2"></img>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid={true} className="p-0">
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12} lg={12}>
                        {FacilitiesInfo.map((show) =>{
                            const {BottomLeftImg, BottomRightImg, Id} = show
                            return(
                                <div key={Id} className="FacilitiesImg">
                                    <img src={BottomLeftImg} alt="Image 3"></img>
                                    <img src={BottomRightImg} alt="Image 4"></img>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Facilities
```

Comment: Can `FacilitiesInfo` be structured differently or is that not able to be changed?  Also if it has to be an array of objects, is the order guaranteed?  i.e. will `De Spa` always be the first element?  Answering these will help to handle how the button clicks get the right data.

Comment: it will not be able to change, the order will stay the same

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to determine what you're actually trying to accomplish but you can map over your array, and grab the index of the facility that is clicked and do a look up to get the description. Then you can do whatever you want with that description (ex: set as state, insert into HTML to display message, etc.)

```
const FacilitiesInfo = [
    {
        Name: "De' Spa",
        Description: 'Spa Description is here',
        OpeningHours: 'Opening Hours: 10.00am - 8.00pm',
        UpperLeftImg: 'kamar1.jpg',
        BottomLeftImg: 'IMG_9299.jpg',
        UpperRightImg: '',
        BottomRightImg: '',
        Id: '1'
    },
    {
        Name: "De' Resto",
        Description:
            "De' Resto is a restaurant in our hotel that serves up gourment and familiar savory food for breakfast, lunch and dinner. Room service available for 24 hours with many selction guaranteed to satisfy you anytime in the privacy of your room.",
        OpeningHours: 'Open for 24 hours',
        UpperLeftImg: '',
        BottomLeftImg: '',
        UpperRightImg: '',
        BottomRightImg: '',
        Id: '2'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Meeting Room',
        Description: 'Meeting Room Description is here',
        OpeningHours: 'Reservation by Whatsapp: +62-8234-6528-886',
        UpperLeftImg: '',
        BottomLeftImg: '',
        UpperRightImg: '',
        BottomRightImg: '',
        Id: '3'
    }
];


const displayDescription = (index) => {
    const chosenFacility = FacilitiesInfo[index];

    // This value is the description for the clicked button, do anything you want with it
    console.log(chosenFacility.Description);
}


const Facilities = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {FacilitiesInfo.map((facility, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <button
                            onClick={(index) => {
                                displayDescription(index);
                            }}
                        >
                            {facility.Name}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Facilities;
```